# External IP adress in vue project

Tags: vue.js, ip

When making external requests in Vue 3 with Vite, my computer's external IP is being used as 222.94.192.96, while in Vue 2 with vue-cli-service, it's using the proxy's external IP as 45.88.40.25. How can I ensure consistency in the external IP address used for requests across both Vue 2 and Vue 3 projects?

vue.config.js file in vue2

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://restapi.amap.com/v3",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/api": "",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

vite.config.js file in vue3

```js
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    open: true,
    hmr: {
      overlay: false,
    },
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://restapi.amap.com/v3/",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (p) => {
          return p.replace(/^\/api/, "");
        },
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

When making identical requests to https://restapi.amap.com/v3/ip?key=xxx using Vue 2 and Vue 3, I am receiving different responses for location data. In Vue 2, I receive:

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "info": "OK",
    "infocode": "10000",
    "province": [],
    "city": [],
    "adcode": [],
    "rectangle": []
}
```

While in Vue 3, I receive:

```json
{
    "status": "1",
    "info": "OK",
    "infocode": "10000",
    "province": "江苏省",
    "city": "南京市",
    "adcode": "320100",
    "rectangle": "118.4253323,31.80452471;119.050169,32.39401346"
}
```

Why am I getting different responses for the same request in Vue 2 and Vue 3, and how can I achieve consistent behavior across both versions?"